# How to get a item from a array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
my_array = [
  {
    :id => 1,
    :name => "Bill"
  },
  {
    :id => 2,
    :name => "Joe"
  },
  {
    :id => 3,
    :name => "Bob"
  }
]
```

How can I get an item passing the ID, for example, given 3 as the 'id' I'd like to get the hash: `{"id": 3, "nome": "Bob"}`.

**UPDATE**:

I discovered the answer, using the method `.selec` as follows:

```
my_array.select { |a| a[:id] == 1 }
```

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Ruby code, maybe it is the JSON representation of a hash?

Comment: I corrected the question @toro2k

Answer (score 4):

What you have is a JSON string. You will need to parse it into an array of hashes first and then use [`Enumerable#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to get the item:

```
require 'json'

test = '[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "Bill"
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "nome": "Joe"
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "nome": "Bob"
 }
]'

# Parse into an array of hashes
hashes = JSON.parse(test)

foundItem = hashes.find { |item| item["id"] == 3}
puts foundItem
```

Comment: Kalman Hazins, please see my edition.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like `jSON` you should parse as above if it is an actual array of `Hash`es you can do this

```
 arr = [{"id" => 1,"nome"=> "Bill"},{"id"=> 2,"nome"=> "Joe"},{"id"=> 3,"nome"=> "Bob"}]
 arr.select{|h| h["id"] == 3}
 #=>[{"id"=> 3,"nome"=> "Bob"}]
```

This will return an `Array` of all matching `Hash`

To get a single value you can use

```
 arr.select{|h| h["id"] == 3}.pop
 #=>{"id"=> 3,"nome"=> "Bob"}
```

Which will return the last matching `Hash` Or as @KalmanHazins stated

```
arr.find{|h| h["id"] == 3}
#=>{"id"=> 3,"nome"=> "Bob"}
```

Which will return the first `Hash` that matches based on current order